# Explain mod_rewrite issue

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I changed the permalink structure of my wordpress site from `/%postname%.html` to `/%postname%/`. I want to redirect all the old urls to the new structure, so I added the following to my .htaccess: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+).html$ /$1/`. So now my .htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+).html$ /$1/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It redirects my old post urls just fine, but it messes up my homepage. If I tried to go to the root of my site `/` it redirects to `/index/`.

Can someone explain why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I changed my DirectoryIndex so it went straight to index.php:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+).html$ /$1/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```